# ng-model color (in angular dart)

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am trying to bind color input using ng-model. In the following code:

```dart
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="col in ctrl.maincols">
<p>{{col.attr}}:{{col.value}}
  <input type="color" ng-model="col.value"></p>
  </li>
   </ul>
```

there is no reaction when I select a colour. However if I change the input type to text everything works fine.

Any suggestions for making this work, or an alternative to ng-model for this use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems an editor for `<input type="color">` is not yet implemented

see https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/lib/directive/ng_model.dart

You could try to copy a similar and customize it to your needs.
You could also create a feature request. Please add a link here if you do.

Comment: Thanks. I filed a feature request at: https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/1077

Comment: Just landed in the repo https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/pull/1080#issuecomment-49691297